# How to extract network information from the Azure VM one is currently running on?

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I want to know the network information e.g. subnet from the Azure VM I am currently working on. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The [metadata information endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/instance-metadata-service?tabs=linux) can be used to extract this information:

**Azure CLI with PowerShell Core**

```
$vmInfo = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{"Metadata" = "true" } -Method GET -NoProxy -Uri "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2021-02-01"

$nicId = az vm show --subscription $vmInfo.compute.subscriptionId --resource-group $vmInfo.compute.resourceGroupName --name $vmInfo.compute.name --query networkProfile.networkInterfaces[0].id --output tsv

$subnetId = az network nic show --ids $nicId --query ipConfigurations[0].subnet.id --output tsv
```

**Azure CLI with Bash**

```
name=`curl -s -H Metadata:true --noproxy "*" "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2021-02-01" | jq -r .compute.name`
subscriptionId=`curl -s -H Metadata:true --noproxy "*" "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2021-02-01" | jq -r .compute.subscriptionId`
resourceGroupName=`curl -s -H Metadata:true --noproxy "*" "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2021-02-01" | jq -r .compute.resourceGroupName`

nicId=`az vm show --subscription $subscriptionId --resource-group $resourceGroupName --name $name --query networkProfile.networkInterfaces[0].id --output tsv`
subnetId=`az network nic show --ids $nicId --query ipConfigurations[0].subnet.id --output tsv`
```